# jquery, selector access by "nephew"

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to access at class by "nephew" selector for add filter.
if add only parent, this get only a first parent.
you can help me to get a second parent? i tried .parent().parent() but without success

```html
<div class="all-types">
 <div class="row typeprices mar0 js_item"></div>
</div>   
<div class="box-show-alltypes"><a class="js_show_alltypes">GO</a></div>
```

```
$('.js_show_alltypes').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().find('.js_item').slideDown();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: You may need to add `.closest()`.

Comment: Did you try .parents()?  https://api.jquery.com/parents/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.closest()`/`.parent()` to get to current element parent, then use `.prev()` to target its sibling after wards `.find()` to target the element

```
$(this).closest('.box-show-alltypes').prev().find('.js_item').slideDown();
```

If you can wrap the element in a common parent i.e. `.common-parent` then just traverse up to it using  `.closest()` and directly use `.find()`

```
$(this).closest('.common-parent').find('.js_item').slideDown();
```

```js
$('.js_show_alltypes').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.box-show-alltypes').prev().find('.js_item').slideDown();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
.js_item{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="all-types">
 <div class="row typeprices mar0 js_item">js_item</div>
</div>   
<div class="box-show-alltypes"><a class="js_show_alltypes">GO</a></div>
```